# problem with USB devices

Tags: 11.10, usb

I have changed my OS from windows XP to ubuntu and all USB devices (USB hdd, flash disk, usb webcam and others) are not noticed. All these devices were fully functional on my computer when I had windows xp. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

The USB bug is actually a HW issue, as I get it in both Windows and Lubuntu.
Turns out that shutting down (if you can, my system freezes up and REISUB doesn't work) and then disconnecting Power to the Power Supply for a few minutes fixes the problem.

Here's a thread where I found the workaround: [SOLVED USB 2/3 device descriptor read64, error -110](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1610142)

Answer (score 1):

Open a Terminal and issue the command:

```
lsusb
```

As a new user the devices may be recognized, but you don't realize it.

To test the webcam, I like the Cheese application.

If it is not installed, from the terminal you can issue the command:

```
sudo aptitude install cheese
```

The cheese application will then be available for your usage.

A valuable command for new users is:

`tail -f /var/log/syslog` (or `/var/log/messages` if older distro)

Issue the above command in a terminal and then plug in a usb device. The output is the system recognizing the device and will give you insight into how Linux 'sees' those devices.

Comment: when I issue lsusb to terminal it write to me that i have connected usb keyboard and nothing more (no webcam, usb hdd, no flash disk). Cheese app is saying to me that i havo no webcam connected, but i have connected it. when i isuue command tail -f /var/log/syslog it write:

Comment: Feb 25 11:22:36 computer kernel: [ 1120.860034] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Feb 25 11:22:51 computer kernel: [ 1136.076085] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Feb 25 11:22:51 computer kernel: [ 1136.292097] usb 4-2: new full speed USB device number 13 using uhci_hcd
Feb 25 11:23:06 computer kernel: [ 1151.404111] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110

Comment: Feb 25 11:23:21 computer kernel: [ 1166.620104] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Feb 25 11:23:22 computer kernel: [ 1166.836126] usb 4-2: new full speed USB device number 14 using uhci_hcd
Feb 25 11:23:32 computer kernel: [ 1177.244757] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 14, error -110
Feb 25 11:23:32 computer kernel: [ 1177.356108] usb 4-2: new full speed USB device number 15 using uhci_hcd
Feb 25 11:23:42 computer kernel: [ 1187.764117] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 15, error -110

Comment: Feb 25 11:23:42 computer kernel: [ 1187.764163] hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2

Comment: If you can put the 2 hd's into a windows box and make sure that you "safely remove" them. Then try them again in Linux. Sometimes if usb drives are not unmounted properly they can't be read. Try again with the tail -f command and hopefully they will mount. The webcam doesn't look so promising. If you can, please provide more info on the webcam like make and model #.

Comment: my webcam is 'Logitech QuickCam Connect' and when i tried connect flash disk or usb hdd to win7 and safely remove them lsusb does not show it. (It does not show webcam, too)

Comment: for the usb drives use tail -f /var/log/syslog and then plug in the drives. post the output.

Comment: It shows 'randomly' theese messages:

Comment: Feb 26 14:03:35 computer kernel: [  275.576062] usb 1-6: new high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd                                                                    
Feb 26 14:03:35 computer kernel: [  275.648379] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 6

Comment: try this:http://www.geekdevs.com/2010/04/solved-unable-to-enumerate-usb-device-disabling-ehci_hcd/

Comment: I tried that and at first my flash disk was recognised, then I try to connect my HDD, in lsusb it was, but to in 'this computer'. Then i connect my webcam, it wasn't in lsusb and cheese app doesn't recognise any webcam. After all I connect my flash disk again and it was not neither in lsusb nor in 'this computer'